# Etcd: how to check that each node can see each other

Tags: zabbix, etcd

I have 3 etcd nodes on VMs (not k8s).
There was such problem that nodes are alive but can't see each other, error "connection timeout" during health check. But every single node has "alive" status and zabbix with "etcd by http" template doesn't generate any alerts.

Is there any way to check nodes visibility and to monitor it using zabbix?

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon the version you run, here's an example to do this with 3.5.2

Command
`ETCDCTL_API=3 ./bin/etcdctl endpoint status --cluster -w table --endpoints="member1.etcd:2384,member2.etcd:2384,member3.etcd:2384"`

Output:

```
|                  ENDPOINT                  |        ID        | VERSION | DB SIZE | IS LEADER | IS LEARNER | RAFT TERM | RAFT INDEX | RAFT APPLIED INDEX | ERRORS |
+--------------------------------------------+------------------+---------+---------+-----------+------------+-----------+------------+--------------------+--------+
| http://member1.etcd:2384 | 17ef476d9d7fec5f |   3.5.2 |  1.5 MB |     false |      false |         7 |      20033 |              20033 |        |
| http://member2.etcd:2384 | 31e0ca30ec3c9d94 |   3.5.2 |  1.5 MB |     false |      false |         7 |      20033 |              20033 |        |
| http://member3.etcd:2384 | 721948abbb0522bd |   3.5.2 |  1.5 MB |     false |      false |         7 |      20033 |              20033 |        |
+--------------------------------------------+------------------+---------+---------+-----------+------------+-----------+------------+--------------------+--------+
```